# Python Guess the Word Game

Tags: python, list

**Describing the game if you know what means word guessing dont bother to read** 
Hey! I know I opened a question about that earlier but again Im stuck in another situation. I making a game that there is a list full of words and computer choses a random word in it. And program asking to person guess a letter. If it is in letter it should write the letter in exact order in that word. Lets say our word is word. 
If user input is "w", program will print "w___" and again 
if user says "o" program will print "wo__" like that.

**What is the issue?** 
I did achieve to print if user input in that word and in which order in that word but when user guess again when he got right in first letter my print variable refreshing and prints just last guessed letter.

*Let me explain*
My word again "word" and user guess "w" letter first.
So program will print "w___"
But when user guess again and lets say he/she guessed "o" this time.
Program prints just "_.o__" but not w.

**What I want to do**

1. Program should keep the last data as "w___" and add "o" letter to second place.
2. Program should have an if statment and two variables. First is guess_count and other is error_count.

- If player guessed right increase guess_count by one and

> if guess_count == 5 # word's total letter number: print("Win"), break the loop

- If player guessed wrong increase error_count by one and

> if error_count == 3 # if player type 3 wrong letter: print("Lose"), break the loop

**My code**

*Create a loop*

```py
    run = True
    while run:
```

*Create a namelist and chose a random name*

```
   name_list = ["sound"]
   pick_word = random.choice(name_list)
```

*Create a while loop again* # whole code is under this

> while True:

*Get user input*

> user_input = input("Guess a letter: ")

*Creating if statment if for if input len > 1 get error*

## Whole if true code in there

```
if len(user_input) == 1:
```

*Create a variable that gets user input in order of word as number. 
(I cant say that sentence in english)

> index = pick_word.index(user_input)

*Replace the order number to user input*

> word_tracker[index] = user_input

*Create a string to print it*

> word = "".join(word_tracker)

*Print it*

> print(word)

*Increase guess_count*

> count += 1

*If guess_count is 5 break the loop*

> if count == 5:

*If guess not in word*

```py
  except ValueError:
      print("You couldnt guess the letters.")
      guessing += 1
      if guessing == 3:
          print("Peh")
          exit()
```

*If guessed letter not 1 character*

```
else:
   print("You allowed to type just one letter")
```

I hope I wont get ban haha

Comment: have you given it a go? what errors arose?

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service please make sure to get a [tour[(https://stackoverflow/tour) and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I didnt remember that ı didnt share the code. Chill what is -5 vote

Comment: I did write every possible question and describe everythind in question. I didnt ask a solution I want to somebody tell what did I wrong. But I did read my question again and it seems like I want somebody to write my code. I didnt mean it.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
word_tracker[index] = user_input
```

to

```
word_tracker.append(user_input)
```

That is if 'word_tracker' is a list

Comment: word_tracker is not list its just here to put to letter in a order. But thank you for answering question got -5 because I over described it I guess